# Merging a formerly deleted file in Git

Tags: git, merge

I have two repositories that I manage - example_set and son_of_example_set.

In the past, I deleted a file - lost_file.html - from son_of_example_set because it wasn't relevant to that project.

Now lost_file.html is relevant to the son_of_example_set project, and so I've recreated lost_file.html in the son_of_example_set repository.  When I pull from the example_set repository, I want to include any changes that have happened and are happening to lost_file.html.

When I pull example_set into son_of_example_set I receive the "Already up-to-date" message - even though lost_file.html has changed in example_set.

How can I incorporate past and future changes to lost_file.html in the example_set repository into lost_file.html in the son_of_example_set repository?

Answer (score 0):

So example_set (let's call it ES) is the upstream repo and son_of_example_set (SOES) is the downstream repo. You need to work inside ES. Merge SOES/master into ES/master, resolving any conflicts raised in lost_file.html. Then go back to the SOES repo, and merge ES/master into SOES/master.